# Fret wear issue on new Martin guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I  got my first Road series Martin guitar about 6 months ago , Played for about 1 hour a day
Already have fret wear.

I know how hard I press frets and my playing style does affect how soon fret wear happens
but I have 4 other guitars it seems to me that Martin frets are not that strong.

Will silk and steel strings put less pressure on frets?

Comment: This sounds like a warranty issue. Martin offers a limited lifetime warranty to the original buyer. As for silk and steel strings, they do have slightly less tension than regular strings but that only pertains to the wound strings. Having less tension and being slightly softer may possibly contribute to less fret wear. However you shouldn’t have to resort to a specific string type on a guitar to keep it from wearing too quickly.

Comment: There is no customer service in my country for Martin and the seller says it is a normal fretwear and I should change my playing style , Less pressure on strings.

Answer (score 3):

Martin's general warranty has an exclusion for frets. You can read it online at martin guitar.com. (See below). That being said, as a customer you should contact Martin directly by email or phone and tell them your experience and concern, which I would state more or less as...."while frets are excluded from warranty and by nature of what they are, are subject to wear at levels that can vary from player to player, the wear they are showing after six months of use appears to be more than I would expect, given the level of use I have applied to them as the owner and sole player of the instrument"....attach photos of the frets and make sure the worn areas are clearly and easily seen.

I am not sure what material is used on that series frets, Martin has used Jescar frets, nickel/silver and stainless steel are both common materials, stainless steel being the hardest. You might inquire as to the exact material and manufacturer of the frets for your guitar, referencing the serial number, and see what it is.

I would not suggest changing a playing style to accommodate the instrument, rather, get the instrument that best serves the playing style.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Martin's "LIMITED WARRANTY EXCLUSIONS"

1. This Limited Warranty does not cover normal wear and tear to the instrument, including certain components.

The following components are subject to wear and tear as a result of normal use, and therefore, are excluded from this Limited Warranty, unless C. F. Martin determines that damage to such aforementioned components resulted from defective materials or workmanship:

• tuning hardware;
• fingerboards;
• bridges;
• bridge plates;
• bridge pins; • saddles;
• end pins;
• strings;
• **frets;**
• nuts; and
• pickguards.